# Cannot drop index '***': needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have created unique index:

```
 $table->unique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

and now i tray drop it

```
$table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

> General error: 1553 Cannot drop index
>   'connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique': needed in a foreign key
>   constraint (SQL: alter table connections drop index
>   connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique)

Also, i tried to drop foreign key before

```
$table->dropForeign('connections_promoter_id_foreign');
```

but still no results

Comment: That's because the name of the foreign key is `connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique`, as the error tells you

Comment: @DouwedeHaan but how i can drop it (unique), i know what error say, but i do not know how i can solve

Comment: `$table->dropForeign('connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique');`

Comment: @DouwedeHaan this does not work too, i still got the error (different), that this key does not exist

Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `connections` drop foreign key `connections_owner_id_promoter_id_unique`)

Comment: Can you provide us the all the migrations for the table you want to alter and it's related tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Laravel docs on Indexes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes), you can create the unique index with an assigned name:

> Laravel will automatically generate a reasonable index name, but you may pass a second argument to the method to specify the name yourself:

```
$table->unique('email', 'unique_email');
```

So just to save you of debugging how laravel constructs the name to the index, you may assign it a name when adding the index e.g:

```
$table->unique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id'], 'owner_promoter_index');
```

Then when you drop it, you use the same name:

```
$table->dropUnique('owner_promoter_index');
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems suppose to work, but for this i needed to add index to older migration

Comment: @napalias you don't have to do this for older migrations if they don't give you problem. For me, giving the index a name I chose (when there's a problem) make me confident that the right name is being used, therefore if there comes another problem afterwards I can exclude the index naming from the root cause.

Comment: If you  use an array,  Laravel will automatically resolve it to correct index name. So `$table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id'])` will remove the correct key. But that was not the problem of OP, problem was conflict with index and foreignkey, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73730681/2311074

Answer (score 8):

From the error message, it seems that you created a foreign key and the unique touple in the same run, like this:

```
$table->foreignId('owner_id')->constrained('owners');
$table->unique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

From [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html):

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a
> table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an
> index is created.

Now as you created a tuple index, `owner_id` already has an index (because its the first of the tuple, note `promoter_id` does not have an index) and there is no need for MySQL to create a foreign_key index. However, if you would remove the unique key constrain now, you would have a foreignkey without index. This is not allowed, and therefore your error message.

There is no need to remove the foreign key. Just add a normal index on the field before you remove the unique index. Like this:

```
$table->index('owner_id');
$table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

That's it. The foreign key error won't appear, as you have it indexed.

Comment: Thanks.. this explains a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [Drop muli-column unique key without dropping foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856568/drop-muli-column-unique-key-without-dropping-foreign-key) i got this solution which also works:

```
Schema::table('connections', function ($table){
            $table->index('owner_id');
            $table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

in your example

```
$table->unique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

the first column in the array already has a foreign key and a related index.

**The First option** would be to put first a field that does not have a foreign key already, like

```
$table->unique(["key", 'owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

But it is not always possible

**The second option** - you just need to modify the `down()` function

For example you create your unique index like this

```
$table->unique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

`owner_id` is the field that gives you troubles now because it goes the first in the array. Thus, the `down` function should look like this:

```
$table->dropForeign(['owner_id']);
$table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
$table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('owners');
```

**The third option** is a bit trickier, your 'down' function will look like this

```
$table->index('owner_id');
$table->dropUnique(['owner_id', 'promoter_id']);
```

It will work, but *I don't recommend it*, because it is not quite a `rollback'

If you start with index name `records_owner_id_foreign`
then you do `php artisan migrate` and then `php artisan migrate:rollback`
and then you will find your index name `records_owner_id_index`. It is not the same index name any more

So potentially you can have different index names in different databases, do you like it? I don't.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, great write up!

Comment: I think he never wanted to do a rollback. Its normal that you set a unique key and have to remove it in a later migration due to business changes. In this case, I think third option is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
   Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
        
        //$table->dropIndex('language_title');            
        //$table->dropUnique('language_title');

        // Integrate them
        $table->dropIndex('language_title')->dropUnique('language_title');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Drop the constraint first.

for sqlserver:
if you don't know the constraint name,use `sp_helpconstraint TABLE_A`，the constraint name maybe the same as index.
then `alter table TABLE_A drop constraint UQ__TABLE_A_XXXXXXXXXX`.Then,drop the index.

Answer (score -1):

NO NEED to disable or delete unique index! Just override the UNIQUE index with another one!

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unique(['user_id', 'role_id', 'department_id'],
       'user_roles_user_id_role_id_department_id_unique');
});
```